# Permalink with a Category and then a Post

Tags: multisite, permalinks

I have a multsite Wordpress install and each site can have their own categories. I would like the site URL to be the new site name and then a cateogry and a post or page name.

For example, if I have a category of football, I'd like my URL to be something like:
website.com/site-name/football

This would automatically display all the posts for the football category. If I click on the post the link would be something like:
website.com/site-name/football/this-is-a-post

The same thing would be for pages as well. I had a page called gallery, I'd like my URL to be something like:
website.com/site-name/football/gallery

I tried to update my permalink structure to be:
`/%category%/%postname%/`

If I then go to:
website.com/site-name/football

I get a 404 even though I know I have posts with this category. Any ideas how to have this work with the permalinks?

Comment: the permalink structure for a single post isn't related to the permalink of a category archive, that's a separate setting: category base. there are plugins for removing category base, but you'll still have issues with pages also sharing the same permalink structure as posts- how does WordPress know if `gallery` is supposed to be a post or a page? there's nothing unique in the URL that would identify what you're requesting.

Comment: @Milo Do you have any recommendations on how to achieve this result then?

Comment: My recommendation is to abandon this effort and just use the urls that WordPress generates.

Answer (score 2):

`/football` is not a valid permalink natively because taxonomy base `/category/football` is used to reliably distinguish permalinks between different objects (or you might get unholy collisions).

There are some answer on this site (as well as plugins around, for example [FV Top Level Categories](https://wordpress.org/plugins/fv-top-level-cats/)) for removing category base but it's considered highly error–prone configuration.